# Acts as Votable errors after user logs out

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have implemented act as votable, everything works well as long as a user is logged in, once a user logs out, I get the following error.

```html
  undefined method `voted_up_on?' for nil:NilClass
```

My index.html.erb

```html
<p class="small-text float center ">
      <% if current_user.voted_up_on?(startup) %>
       <%= link_to '<i class="material-icons md-light">change_history</i>
       </br>'.html_safe, downvote_startup_path(startup), method: :put %> 
       <small>votes: <%= startup.get_upvotes.size %></small>   
      

      <% current_user && current_user.voted_down_on?(startup) %>
       <%= link_to  '<i class="material-icons md-dark">change_history</i>
       </br> '.html_safe, upvote_startup_path(startup), method: :put  %> 
       <small>votes: <%= startup.get_upvotes.size %></small> 
      <% end %>
     </p>
```

My Controller

```html
before_action :find_startup, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy, :update, :upvote, :downvote]

def upvote
  @startup.upvote_from current_user
  redirect_to @startup, notice: "Upvoted successfully!"
 end

 def downvote
  @startup.downvote_from current_user
  redirect_to @startup, notice: "downvoted successfully!"
 end
```

My routes

```html
resources :startups do
    member do
      put :upvote
      put :downvote
    end
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **index.html.erb** you have this line of code `<% if current_user.voted_up_on?(startup) %>`, when you logout `current_user` method will be nil. Ensure that the `current_user` value is not nil before rendering the logic in your `index.html.erb`

something like

```
<% if current_user %>
  ...
  # your logic that makes use of current_user object goes here
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that after the user logs out you have no `current_user`.  So the easiest solution to this would be to verify there is a current user first.

```
<p class="small-text float center ">
  <% if current_user && current_user.voted_up_on?(startup) %>
    <%= link_to '<i class="material-icons md-light">change_history</i>
    </br>'.html_safe, downvote_startup_path(startup), method: :put %>   
    <small>votes: <%= startup.get_upvotes.size %></small>       
    <% end %> <--  couldn't find the closing end so maybe it goes here?         

    <% if current_user && current_user.voted_down_on?(startup) %>
        <%= link_to  '<i class="material-icons md-dark">change_history</i>
        </br> '.html_safe, upvote_startup_path(startup), method: :put  %> 
        <small>votes: <%= startup.get_upvotes.size %></small> 
   <% end %>
</p>
```

Your code was a little confusing, I think that second part was also an `if` conditional but maybe you forgot to write the `if`?  Either way the fix is the check for current user in that first `if` conditional because a user can also access this page without being logged in, so you need to check for that, otherwise you are calling `voted_up_on?` on a `nil` object.